# Editing tags of inherited attributes in golang?

Tags: json, go

```
type Parent struct {
    Name string `json:"parent_name"`
}

type Child struct {
    Parent
}
```

Say I have two structs `Parent` and `Child`.  I have two endpoints that read `json` using those two structs.

```
// Sample Parent endpoint payload
{
    "parent_name": "Parent Name"
}

// Sample Child endpoint payload
{
    "child_name": "Child Name"
}
```

Both structs are being used to store similar data, but the `json` key is different for each endpoint payload.  Is there a way to edit the `json` tag on the `Child` struct such that `Child` still inherits from `Parent`, but the tag is now `json:"child_name"`?

Comment: Stop thinking like this. Child does **not** "inherit" anything from Parent. Really. Nothing. Stop thinking like this. Embedding anonymous fields is syntactic sugar which spares you unnecessary typing, it has nothing to do with "inheritance". So to answer your question. No you cannot do this.

Answer (score 3):

*Go doesn't have inheritance, only composition.* Instead of parent-child relationship think about it in terms of part-whole.

In your example you can use  a mix of `json:",omitempty"` tag and "field shadowing" to get the result:

```
type Parent struct {
    Name string `json:"parent_name,omitempty"`
}

type Child struct {
    Parent
    Name string `json:"child_name"`
}
```

Playground: http://play.golang.org/p/z72dCKOhYC.

But this still misses the point (and breaks if `child.Parent.Name` isn't empty). If you're going to "override" a field in every struct that embeds `Parent`, why is it even there in the first place?